# Filtering table rows in SQL based on another query response (multiple values)

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and would appreciate help:

I have these tables:

```
Table GENERAL:
ID IN OUT
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
8  2  4
9  2  4

Table IN:
ID TYPE
2  1
4  2
5  1
9  1
```

Step 1: I want to get from Table IN all ID's of TYPE 1.
Step 2: Then I want to filter out all the rows of Table GENERAL that their IN column is not in the results I got from step 1.

So in the toy case above after step 1 I get the colum of ID's with values {2,5,9} and then in step 2 I use these values to filter my table to get:

```
ID IN OUT
1  2  3
4  5  6
8  2  4
9  2  4
```

I think I'm fine with step 1, but step 2 is not working for me.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM GENERAL
WHERE GENERAL.IN in (
SELECT IN.ID as in_id
FROM IN
WHERE IN.TYPE = 1)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Note that `IN` is not a wise choice for a table or a column, since it does conflict with the corresponding SQL keyword.

Comment: *not working* - means what exactly?

Comment: I gave IN another name and its still not working. 
" invalid argument types for function '=' "

Answer (score 0):

As I did not get the database and version, I tried below with oracle (`in` is reserved in Oracle and I had to change it to in1) to check the validity of the SQL in general and I dont see any issue. Coming to the error  `" invalid argument types for function '=' "`, please check the data type compatibility of column TYPE with number/int in that database.

```
drop table general;
create table general (id number, in1 number, out number);
drop table in1;
create table in1 (id number, type number);

insert into general (id, in1, out) values(1, 2, 3);
insert into general (id, in1, out) values(4,  5,  6);
insert into general (id, in1, out) values(7,  8,  9);
insert into general (id, in1, out) values(8,  2,  4);
insert into general (id, in1, out) values(9,  2,  4);

insert into in1 (id, type) values(2,1);
insert into in1 (id, type) values(4,2);
insert into in1 (id, type) values(5,1);
insert into in1 (id, type) values(9,1);

commit;

SELECT *
FROM GENERAL
WHERE GENERAL.IN1 in (
SELECT IN1.ID as in_id
FROM IN1
WHERE IN1.TYPE = 1);
```

Result:

```
ID  IN1 OUT
1   2   3
8   2   4
9   2   4
4   5   6
```